# How to embed Stripe Pricing tables in Angular app

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-payments-js

Reading Stripe docs regarding the embeddable [Pricing tables](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/pricing-table) feature - I have constructed a pricing table following the steps as described.

This results in a code snippet that can be used to embed the hosted pricing table on one's own website/application.

**Example snippet;**

```
<script async src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/pricing-table.js"></script>
<stripe-pricing-table pricing-table-id="xxx_xxxxxxxxxx"
publishable-key="pk_test_xxxxxxxxxx">
</stripe-pricing-table>
```

The examples in the docs relating to how to embed this snippet give only **HTML and React examples**.

I'd like to know how to achieve the same result in angular.

I have attempted to use Stipe Elements to build an element to hold the pricing table, but Elements does not seem to have a component for the new Pricing tables.

Comment: Angular is not supported yet for stripe-pricing-table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes at the moment Stripe Docs has no information for Angular.
Here is my solution suggestion with dynamic attribute placement from component to html view.

**1. index.html**

```
<head>
  <!-- Paste the script snippet in the head of your app's index.html -->
  <script async src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/pricing-table.js"></script>
</head>
```

**2) in xyz.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    XyzComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [...],
  schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
  ]
})
```

**3. in xyz.component.ts**

```
public stripe_key: string = 'pk_test_***';
public stripe_table: string = 'prctbl_***'
```

**4. in xyz.componet.html**

```
<stripe-pricing-table 
   [attr.pricing-table-id]="stripe_table"
   [attr.publishable-key]="stripe_key">
</stripe-pricing-table>
```

If you don't need dynamic **publishable-key** and **pricing-table-id** skip point 3 and hardcode point 4, as here:

**xyz.componet.html**

```
<stripe-pricing-table 
   pricing-table-id="prctbl_***"
   publishable-key="pk_test_***">
</stripe-pricing-table>
```

Comment: I used this method you posted but there is a challenge I encountered per this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76066094/properties-in-an-angular-component-are-null-when-the-component-is-rendered?noredirect=1#comment134152578_76066094
Any idea why or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution and processed as followed :

1. Integrate the stripe script file inside your index.html.
2. Create and extends a component with HTMLElement and do as they say [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69027359/creating-a-simple-web-component-that-injects-a-html-line-and-runs-a-js-function)
3. Then you had CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA from Angular core to your module :

   @NgModule({
   ...
   schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
   })
4. Finally, call your component which embed the stripe pricing table web component and your pricing table will shows up properly in an Iframe.